# Is it possible to convert RGB images to indexed colors such that each index color corresponds to proper RGB color in the matrix form in Python?

Tags: python, indexing, colors

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/fikrat/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/separate'):
    for files in sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd())):
        if files.endswith(".png") and files == str(count) + "Above" + ".png":
            print(files)
            img = cv2.imread(files, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            height = image.shape[0]
            width = image.shape[1]
            array = np.zeros([height, width], dtype=np.uint8)

            colors = set()
            for h in range(image.shape[0]):
                for w in range(image.shape[1]):
                    pixel = image[h, w]
                    color = str(pixel[0]) + ' ' + str(pixel[1]) + ' ' + str(pixel[2])
```

This python code implies reading all images from directory in sorted order, then converting them np.zeros array, while loop through pixels of RGB images to define color set.

Moreover, I convert images into np.zeros, because my main target is defining unique colors, in this respect, to determine the corresponding index color which is displayed as the following:

```
{'0 0 0': 0, '255 255 255': 1, '70 130 180': 2, '220 220 0': 3, '0 0 142': 4, '190 153 153': 5, '102 0 204': 6, '128 64 128': 7, '128 128 0': 8, '0 255 255': 9, '255 128 0': 10, '178 132 190': 11, '128 128 64': 12, '180 65 180': 13, '107 142 35': 14, '0 60 100': 15, '0 0 230': 16}
```

Then put these indexes in correct pixel coordinates of the image matrix.